# How to load fine-tuned keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am following [this](https://www.learnopencv.com/keras-tutorial-fine-tuning-using-pre-trained-models/) tutorial to try fine-tuning using VGG16 model, I trained the model and saved `.h5` file using  `model.save_weights` and

```
vgg_conv = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(image_size, image_size, 3))

    # Freeze the layers except the last 4 layers
    for layer in vgg_conv.layers[:-4]:
        layer.trainable = False

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(vgg_conv)
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(11, activation='softmax'))
```

I then tried to rebuild the architecture and load weights using the below

```
def create_model(self):
    model = Sequential()
    vgg_model = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(150, 150, 3))
    model.add(vgg_model)
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(11, activation='softmax'))
    model.load_weights(self.top_model_weights_path) # throws error
    return model
```

but it then throws this error

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (512, 512, 3, 3) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(3, 3, 3, 64)'
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the trainable difference between the two models. If you freeze the 4 last layers in the create_model function, it will work.

But as said by Igna, model.save and model.load_model is simpler.

Comment: it worked, but can you please elaborate regarding the answer ... ? I did'nt think that freeze would affect the required tensor shapes

Comment: I don't know why, I just thought that was the only difference. Wondering if save_weights only saves trainable weights. Answer is certainly in the code. You could also try to use the "by_name" option of the model.load_weights(filepath, by_name=False) function. I suspect the weights from the 4 last layers are not saved, and not restored. It would be worth running some tests to validate this.

Comment: I wonder if it's a bug. I looked at the weights of the different models, and depending on numbers of layers with a frozen parameters, the order of the layers differs when listed with: 
for layer in model.layers:
  print(layer.weights)
But layers are exactly the same, just in different orders.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how to intepret the error but you could try saving the model architecture and the weights together `model.save("model.h5")` after fine tuning.

To load the model you can type

```
model = load_model('model.h5')
# summarize model.
model.summary()
```

I think this has the benefeit of not having to rebuild the model and requires only one line to acomplish the same purpose.